# Detecting All Simple Cycles In Strongly Connected Components(Complexity)

Tags: detection, cycle, graph-theory

I am working with a specific graphical structure representing 2-player normal form games (game theory). I know that I can compute all strongly connected components of the directed graph in O(V+E) via Tarjans, but was wondering what the complexity of computing all of the simple cycles of a strongly connected component is? AND, if there is a known upper bound on the number of such simple cycles given the number of vertices defining the strongly connected component?

I am looking for any literature/algorithms related to both of these problems. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Is the graph directed or undirected? 
In either case, the number of cycles can obviously be exponential in the number of nodes/ edges.  For example, in a complete graph, every single permutation of every possible size from 2 to *n* will result in a cycle.

[Johnson's algorithm](http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf) for enumerating cycles (in directed graphs) seems to be one of the more efficient ones. Given that you are interested in the cycles of a strongly connected component, the implementation is even slightly easier than that described in the paper. The pseudocode in the paper is a little hard to read; this [Ocaml implementation](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/finding-all-elementary-circuits-directed-graph) may be a little easier to process.  The algorithm has complexity *O(n+e)(c+1)*, where *c* is the number of cycles in the graph.